# I want a Discord bot to enter voice channel and play a mp3 file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I suspect there is something wrong with my code but I don't know.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Bot online!');
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if(message.content.voice.channel) {
        const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
        const dispatcher = connection.playFile(require("path").join(__dirname, './audio.mp3'));
        dispatcher.on('start', () => {
            console.log('Now playing!');
        });
        dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
            console.log('Finished playing!');
            voiceChannel.leave();
        });
        dispatcher.on('error', console.error);
    }
});

client.login(config.TOKEN);
```

I get error :

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property
> 'channel' of undefined
> at Client. (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\index.js:10:30)
> at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
> at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
> at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
> at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
> at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
> at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\djd18\Desktop\Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:825:20)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:16536) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 1) (node:16536) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.

Comment: read this link for improve voice https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/topics/voice

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work.